# How to call Java code from an XE5 Android application?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

How to call Java code from an **XE5** Android application? 
like assembly codes in delphi :
 asm
  ...
 end;

Comment: I don't see the relationship between asm and Java. Can you elaborate? I'm concerned that you perhaps expect to be able to write inline Java code.

Comment: You can't write Java code this way. Closest thing I believe you can do is to dynamically load external java libraries. See this: https://plus.google.com/+PaulFoster/posts/Tc7viMithGi